# Tag request :: programming or coding

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There aren't any tags that incorporate programming or coding ([except R](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r)). Perhaps we can consolidate all flavors (SQL, R, python, java, etc) into one tag, i.e. programming, or coding.

I know this **isn't** Stackexchange but many questions are programming specific (i.e [python](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=python)) and I would like a way of viewing these questions, since that is my approach usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great idea! I created the tag for [Programming](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/programming/info). Feel free to edit or suggest changes to make it better.

Comment: Great - thanks. That's a useful tag for finding new questions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if we use a tag for each programming language, we will eventually, steal questions from stack exchange like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999731/json-file-with-jquery).

However, a `programming` tag sounds great to use in questions that are related somehow with any programming language.

Let's see what other users think.